# OneNote add in open winform in context

Tags: onenote

How can I open a winform from a OneNote AddIn without loosing context (still get access to OneNote.Interop ).

Show() and ShowDialog() makes form freeze, Application.Run loose context.

Comment: What do you mean by lose context? What object are you trying to access?